# Code analysis tools for Android

Tags: android, static, code-analysis, static-analysis

Is there any static code analysis tools for Android that would pick up simple things like NullPointerExceptions from trying to access an object that might be null (without checking for it first)...

Tools like resharper on C# projects do this quite well, so I'm presuming there is similar tools for Android's Java...

Comment: Check out Sonarqube - https://androidlearnersite.wordpress.com/2017/02/21/integrating-and-understanding-sonarqube-in-android/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not really android specific, it's Java specific.

Several tools I know of:

1. PMD - [official site](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/)
2. FindBugs - [official site](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/)

---

More complete list of tools can be found on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis#Java).

Comment: Please tell me how can I achieve code checking for a gradle based android studio project. Is there any way to do so using command line. I would prefer a tool which can be controlled using command line as it can be used for continuous integration

Answer (score 6):

Since ADT 16 there is build-int **Android Lint** tool for static code analysis.
http://tools.android.com/tips/lint/

Comment: That link is still valid; this is another which seems more recent ; https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint.html

Answer (score 1):

For static analysis of Android apps, you can use the following combination:

1. Use [DED](http://siis.cse.psu.edu/ded/) to first decompile the apps and get the Java source files
2. Use [SOOT](http://www.sable.mcgill.ca/soot/) to statically analyze the Java source files obtained from the step above

Answer (score 1):

Android specific:

[DidFail](https://www.cert.org/secure-coding/tools/didfail.cfm)

[FlowDroid](http://sseblog.ec-spride.de/tools/flowdroid/)

[IccTA](https://sites.google.com/site/icctawebpage/) (from the creators of FlowDroid)

Answer (score 0):

Try [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) from Jetbrains (the creator of resharper). It has a lot of java code inspections like resharper and support [developing Android applications](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Developing_Android_applications_in_IntelliJ_IDEA).

Answer (score 0):

AndroidStudio is a thin layer on top of IntelliJ IDEA which zloyrobot points out has lots of inspections. The problem is that there are so many inspections that it is difficult to narrow down your queries to pick up only the really good stuff. I developed a profile for that purpose and describe how to use it here: http://superliminal.com/computing/idea_static_analysis.html